# Django with Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

Having problems trying to set a secret key inside an .env instead of the settings.py file

[image]

When I run the heroku config I get the secret key

```
(portfolio) PS C:\Users\arund\Desktop\Code\Django\portfolio-project> heroku config:get SECRET_KEY
value
```

When I run the following I get errors.

```
(portfolio) PS C:\Users\arund\Desktop\Code\Django\portfolio-project> heroku local
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
1:53:57 PM web.1 |  Traceback (most recent call last):
1:53:57 PM web.1 |    File "C:\Users\arund\Desktop\Code\Django\portfolio-project\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
1:53:57 PM web.1 |      main()
1:53:57 PM web.1 |    File "C:\Users\arund\Desktop\Code\Django\portfolio-project\manage.py", line 18, in main
1:53:57 PM web.1 |      execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
1:53:57 PM web.1 |    File "C:\Users\arund\Desktop\Code\Django\portfolio-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
1:53:57 PM web.1 |      utility.execute()
1:53:57 PM web.1 |    File "C:\Users\arund\Desktop\Code\Django\portfolio-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
1:53:57 PM web.1 |      django.setup()
1:53:57 PM web.1 |    File "C:\Users\arund\Desktop\Code\Django\portfolio-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
1:53:57 PM web.1 |      apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
1:53:57 PM web.1 |    File "C:\Users\arund\Desktop\Code\Django\portfolio-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 122, in populate
1:53:57 PM web.1 |      app_config.ready()
1:53:57 PM web.1 |    File "C:\Users\arund\Desktop\Code\Django\portfolio-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 27, in ready
1:53:57 PM web.1 |      self.module.autodiscover()
1:53:57 PM web.1 |    File "C:\Users\arund\Desktop\Code\Django\portfolio-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 24, in autodiscover
1:53:57 PM web.1 |      autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
1:53:57 PM web.1 |    File "C:\Users\arund\Desktop\Code\Django\portfolio-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules
1:53:57 PM web.1 |      import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
1:53:57 PM web.1 |    File "C:\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
1:53:57 PM web.1 |      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
1:53:57 PM web.1 |    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
1:53:57 PM web.1 |    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
1:53:57 PM web.1 |    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
1:53:57 PM web.1 |    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
1:53:57 PM web.1 |    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
1:53:57 PM web.1 |    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
1:53:57 PM web.1 |    File "C:\Users\arund\Desktop\Code\Django\portfolio-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\admin.py", line 6, in <module>
1:53:57 PM web.1 |      from django.contrib.auth.forms import (
1:53:57 PM web.1 |    File "C:\Users\arund\Desktop\Code\Django\portfolio-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 11, in <module>
1:53:57 PM web.1 |      from django.contrib.auth.tokens import default_token_generator
1:53:57 PM web.1 |    File "C:\Users\arund\Desktop\Code\Django\portfolio-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\tokens.py", line 117, in <module>
1:53:57 PM web.1 |      default_token_generator = PasswordResetTokenGenerator()
1:53:57 PM web.1 |    File "C:\Users\arund\Desktop\Code\Django\portfolio-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\tokens.py", line 18, in __init__
1:53:57 PM web.1 |      self.secret = self.secret or settings.SECRET_KEY
1:53:57 PM web.1 |    File "C:\Users\arund\Desktop\Code\Django\portfolio-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 90, in __getattr__
1:53:57 PM web.1 |      raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
1:53:57 PM web.1 |  django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  SIGINT
1:53:57 PM web.1 Exited with exit code null
```

Procfile

[image]

Comment: How does Django get your SECRET_KEY env variable?

Comment: Not completely sure how Django works since it's quite new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django doesn't magically apply environment variables to your settings. You need to do that yourself, e.g. via something like this in your `settings.py`:

```py
import os

SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY", default="dev key")
```

In development, you can use a `.env` file to populate your environment, but that file should not be committed to version control. Ignore it, and use [Heroku's config vars instead](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars). They will be injected into your application's environment.

Comment: So should I remove the .env then insert this where though. Cause it used to be in settings.py

Comment: @ArundeepChohan, keep the `.env` for local development. Some tools, including `heroku local`, use that to populate your environment variables. Then in your `settings.py` you _use_ the environment variables as I have shown here. `.env` sets them, `settings.py` uses them.

Comment: It's currently configured to work locally and not public so I should config a port for like web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:\$PORT  in procfile and then set config for it right.

Comment: Heroku will give you a port via the `PORT` environment variable. For local development you can set your port via something like `PORT=8000` in `.env`, or, more commonly, provide a default right in your `settings.py`: `PORT = os.getenv("PORT", default="8000")`.

Comment: CommandError: "0.0.0.0:\$PORT" is not a valid port number or address:port pair. is what happens then.

Comment: How are you trying to use the port? Please edit that into your question.

Comment: Get rid of the backslash.

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan, "doesn't work" is not a helpful problem description. Please re-read [ask]. And comments aren't for new questions. This question was about how to set settings like your `SECRET_KEY` in an environment variable. I have answered that. If you have a _new_ question about what should go in your `Procfile` please first search for existing questions and then, if you still need to, post a new question.

Comment: Yeah I wrote a new question for it.